# Fileset with several filtering conditions

Tags: ant, fileset

I have the following files and folder :

```
-screen_20_08_2013
 -xxx.html
-connect_21_08_2013
 -contact.html
-screen_22_09_2013
 -yyy.html
-screen_23_09_2013
 -zzz.xml
```

I would like to zip all folders(including the files) containing **screen** after a modified date of **21/08/2013**

I have tried the following:

```
<zip destfile="logs.zip">
   <fileset dir="mydir" excludes="*"> 
     <date datetime="08/21/2013 00:00 AM" when="after"/>
     <include name="**/screen*" />
   </fileset>       
</zip>
```

The datetime filtering is working fine but it does also include folder starting with connect.

I am expecting to have a zip containing:

```
-screen_22_09_2013
 -yyy.html
-screen_23_09_2013
 -zzz.xml
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Just found a way to do it, hope it will help some of you:

```
        <zip destfile="logs.zip">
                <fileset dir="mydir" > 
                    <include name="**/screen*/*"/>
                    <date datetime="08/21/2013 00:00 AM" when="after"/>
                </fileset>          
        </zip>
```